# tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory is not reading all image from directory but only some of it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 9134 files in folder `E:\Desktop\IT FYP\Dataset\train`
In side of this folder there are 4 folders represent 4 classes

```
E:\Desktop\IT FYP\Dataset\train\bee                 #2546 files
E:\Desktop\IT FYP\Dataset\train\otherInsect         #1951 files
E:\Desktop\IT FYP\Dataset\train\otherNonInsect      #684  files
E:\Desktop\IT FYP\Dataset\train\wasp                #3953 files
```

Yet when i use the function `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to load my dataset as following

```
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=("e:/Desktop/IT FYP/Dataset/train"),
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    image_size=(350, 350),
    seed=123,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
class_names = train_dataset.class_names
print(class_names)
```

The console returns the result of

```
Found 2287 files belonging to 4 classes.
['bee', 'otherInsect', 'otherNonInsect', 'wasp']
```

That's not the 9134 files I'm looking for , how do I actually load fully 9134 files from the `train` folder  with this function ? many thanks .

Here is my update : I tried another method as follow to load the data .

```
train_path = "e:/Desktop/IT FYP/Dataset/train"
batch_size = 8 #accessing all our data both training and testing
train_dataset = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./250,zoom_range = 0.2).flow_from_directory(directory = train_path,
                                                  target_size = (150,150),
                                                  batch_size = batch_size,)
```

shockingly , it actually read all of my files totally 9134 and the result on console is as follow .

```
Found 9134 images belonging to 4 classes.
```

Why two different method have different result ? what's the reason ?

Comment: Can you confirm all the files are of same type?

Comment: I have manually look at all files , they are all in jpg format , at least that's what it shown in window 10 file explorer . Though the name of each file is different in format though , eg , some are FF100 , some are ghrsthsetset .

Comment: And the size of each jpg files is different too , from 500x500 to 240x140 , all varies .

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of image processing often on files downloaded from the internet. In some cases these files have errors in them or I want to restrict them to have certain extensions like jpg. So I wrote a test program that given a directory (sdir) the program will go through all the subdirectories of sdir and check all the files to see if they are valid image files and have extensions in a list of acceptable extensions. It also checks that image are rgb, rgba or grayscale. It returns the number of good files, the number of bad files and a list of bad files.

```
import os
import cv2
def check_images(sdir, ext_list, color_mode):
    def inc_bad(bad_count, bad_list, fpath):        
        bad_count +=1
        bad_list.append(fpath)
        return bad_count, bad_list
    def check_color_mode(channels, color_mode, bad_count, bad_list, fpath):
        result=True
        if color_mode==('rgb' and channels !=3) or (color_mode=='rgba' and channels !=4) or (color_mode == 'grayscale' and channels !=1):
            bad_count, bad_list=inc_bad(bad_count, bad_list, fpath)
            result=False        
        return result,bad_count, bad_list            
    good_count=0
    bad_count = 0
    bad_list=[]    
    classlist=os.listdir(sdir)
    print('The classes found are \n', classlist,'\n')
    for klass in classlist:
        print('Processing class ', klass, '\n')
        classpath=os.path.join(sdir, klass)
        if os.path.isdir(classpath):
            flist=os.listdir(classpath)
            for f in flist:
                fpath=os.path.join(classpath, f)                
                if os.path.isfile(fpath):
                    index=f.rfind('.')
                    ext=f[index +1:]
                    if ext.lower() in ext_list:
                        try:
                            img=cv2.imread(fpath)
                            channels=img.shape[2]
                            result,bad_count, bad_list= check_color_mode(channels, color_mode,bad_count, bad_list,fpath)
                            if result:                            
                                good_count +=1 # check_color_mode found no error
                        except:
                            bad_count, bad_list=inc_bad(bad_count, bad_list, fpath)
                            
                    else:
                        bad_count, bad_list=inc_bad(bad_count, bad_list, fpath)
    return good_count, bad_count, bad_list
```

Now specify the sdir where the class sub directories and files are located. Define a list of acceptable extensions, specify the color_mode and call the function

```
sdir=r'c:\temp\people\train'
ext_list=['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']
color_mode='rgb'
good_count, bad_count, bad_files=check_images(sdir, ext_list, color_mode)
print('number of good files is: ', good_count, '\nnumber of bad files is: ', bad_count)
if bad_count>0:
    for f in bad_files:
        print (f)
```

the directory I used has 2 classes savory and unsavory and has a total of 11220 files all in jpg format so the result of running the code is

```
The classes found are 
 ['savory', 'unsavory'] 

Processing class  savory 

Processing class  unsavory 

number of good files is:  11220 
number of bad files is:  0
```